# Autostart bash script, debian 8

Tags: debian

Bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
xflux -l 55 -g 37
```

How autoboot it precisely in debian 8? I.e via "Startap Application" command

gnome-terminal -e /path_to_script/script.sh

Doesn't work

Comment: I think it would help to know what desktop environment you're using - it looks like the default for Debian 8 is Gnome 3.14 and if you're using that then you probably want to make the script executable (chmod +x ~/scripts/start_xflux) and then run that from the Gnome autostart dialogue

Comment: I use cinnamon.

Answer (score 1):

I think this covers your use case:

[Start Script when Gnome Starts Up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8290652)

and involves creating a .desktop file and dropping it in  `~/.config/autostart`:

EG

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyScript
GenericName=A descriptive name
Comment=Some description about your script
Exec=/path/to/my/script.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```